# ¿Cómo recibir un char como double en C?

Tags: c, variables, double, caracteres, cast

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
double datoAgregar = 0;
scanf("%lf", &datoAgregar);
```

Lo que hago es recibir un double (que eventualmente transformaré a int, float o lo dejaré igual, según sea necesario), pero cuando ingreso un carácter cualquiera, este no recibe el int correspondiente del código ASCII, sino que se queda en 0.

Funciona con cualquier otro valor (si agrego un número, sea el número que sea, lo guarda como double), pero al ingresar un carácter no lo guarda de ninguna forma

**¿Cómo puedo recibir un carácter en forma de double desde el teclado?** o a lo mucho poder recibirlo como número (y sin tener que quitar que los otros tipos de dato se guarden como double)

Comment: Tienes que leerlo como un `char` y despues lo haces la conversion

Comment: Hice una solución temporal haciendo eso, pero yo buscaba una solución más universal

Comment: La familia de `scanf` lee por formato, no puedes leer diferentes tipos y que te haga la conversion. Si quieres algo asi, tienes que leer un `char[]` y sacar tu lo que quieras.

Comment: Oooohhh tienes razón, no se me había ocurrido eso, aunque sería un poco lioso pero ya podría recibir los 4 tipos de valores, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomendaría que no usaras `scanf` para leer números en C.
Una de las maneras "más correctas" de leer números en C es leer tu cadena de caracteres y luego transformarla con `strto...`

- Para convertir a enteros existen: [strtol, strtoll](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol), [strtoul y strtoull](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul)
- Para convertir a flotantes extisten: [strtod](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod) y [strtof](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtof)

Las ventajas que proporcionan estas maneras de leer los números incluyen manejo de errores con `errnos`, conversión fácil entre bases (decimal, binario, octal, etc...) y recuperación del texto sobrante.

Una implementación podría ser en una biblioteca que te ayude a manejar las lecturas

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
/**
 * This function reads a number from stdin as string and
 * tries to convert it to a unsigned long long int value
 * @param number The pointer to the variable where the result will be written
 * @param radix The input number radix must be between 2 and 36 inclusive
 */
void readSizeTNumber(size_t * number, unsigned short radix) {
    errno = 0;
    char temp[20];
    fgets(temp, 20, stdin);

    *number = strtoull(temp, NULL, radix);
}

/**
 * This function reads a number from stdin as string and
 * tries to convert it to a double value
 * @param number The pointer to the variable where the result will be written
 */
void readDoubleNumber(double * number) {
    errno = 0;
    char temp[20];

    // Get the input
    fgets(temp, 20, stdin);

    *number = strtod(temp, NULL);
}
```

También esta la manera de castearlos con [`atoi`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) y [`atof`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atof), sin embargo no me parecen tan útiles como `strto...` pues no puedes manejar errores y me parece ser que son implementables únicamente en C11

Comment: Muchas gracias, estuve haciendo algo parecido pero seguía usando el scanf, con esto sirve mejor, gracias