# ¿Cómo puedo llenar una matriz cuadrada sin repetir elementos?

Tags: c, consola

Estoy haciendo un programa en c de aplicación de consola que llena una matriz de 4 x 4 con números enteros. Quiero que si se ingresa un número que ya se ingresó antes marque un mensaje y diga al usuario que ingrese otro número.
Esto es lo que estaba haciendo

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int matriz[4][4], i, j, x, y;
    
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            ingreso:
            do
            {
                    printf("\n\tIngrese el n%cmero de la posici%cn [%d][%d]: ", 163, 162, i+1, j+1);
                    scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
            }while(matriz[i][j] < 1);

            if(j != 0 || i != 0)
            {
                for(x=i; x>=0; x--)
                {
                    for(j=y; j>=0; y--)
                    {
                        if(matriz[x][y] == matriz[i][j])
                        goto ingreso;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
    
    printf("\n\tMatriz capturada\n\t");
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
            printf("%4d", matriz[i][j]);
                    
        printf("\n\t");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Podrías mostrarnos que intentaste hasta ahora?

Answer (score 0):

**Comentarios sobre tu solución:**

- **No números mágicos**

Debes de evitar "números mágicos", o sea números que no sabes de donde salieron, en este caso el 4. ¿De dónde salió ese 4?, ¿Qué significa ese 4?.

Define una constante, preferentemente Macro en este caso para saber que esa constante es el tamaño del arreglo

- **Estudia más sobre arreglos**

Tú mencionas que es una matriz 3x3, sin embargo declaras y recorres una matriz 4x4. Recuerda que los índices empiezan en 0

- **Complejidad computacional**

Si tu ves un programa que tiene muchos ciclos anidados significa que tiene una gran [complejidad computacional](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teor%C3%ADa_de_la_complejidad_computacional), no siempre significa que sea malo, pero realmente uno debe de pensar el algoritmo lo más eficaz posible.

En este caso tienes 6 ciclos anidados, lo cual para la solución de tu problema es catastrófico. (El comentario es con buena intención y para ayudarte a mejorar)

- **Recomendación personal**

El idioma estándar de la programación es el inglés, te recomendaría ir nombrando desde ahora a tus variables en inglés. Ojo, no el texto que se muestra al usuario, sino las variables que usas.

**Solución**

Te recomendaría fragmentar un poco tu código, no sé si hayas ya visto las funciones en C, pero puedes imaginarlas como un pedazo de código que puedes llamar y reutilizar cuando quieras.

En este caso se está implementando la función `isRepeated`, la cual nos regresa un booleano (verdadero o falso | 1 o 0). La cual nos regresa verdadero si el elemento está repetido. ¿Dónde?

En un arreglo llamado `elements`, el cual se va llenando al mismo tiempo que `matrix`, La matriz que quieres llenar con elementos positivos no repetidos.

Esta función comparará si hay algún elemento repetido hasta el elemento `i * MATRIX_SIZE + j` (es el número de elementos que has llenado hasta ahorita de la matriz)

**Nota:** Como verás, dos de las ventajas de no tener números mágicos es que sabes de dónde viene ese número y con sólo modificar tu constante, puedes modificar todo el comportamiento de tu programa.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MATRIX_SIZE 3

/**
 * @param arr
 * @param element
 * @param size
 * @return true if the element is repeated otherwise false
 */
bool isRepeated(const int * arr, int element, unsigned short size) {
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == element)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * @param argc Number of arguments passed on command execution
 * @param argv Array of string arguments
 * @return program exit status
 */
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    int matrix[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];
    int elements[MATRIX_SIZE * MATRIX_SIZE];
    unsigned short i = 0;
    unsigned short j;
    for(; i < MATRIX_SIZE; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE; ++j) {
            do
            {
                printf("\n\tIngrese el n%cmero de la posici%cn [%d][%d]: ", 163, 162, i+1, j+1);
                scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
                elements[i * MATRIX_SIZE + j] = matrix[i][j];
            }while(matrix[i][j] < 1 || isRepeated(elements, matrix[i][j], i * MATRIX_SIZE + j));
        }
    }


    printf("\n\tMatriz capturada\n\t");
    for(i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE; ++j)
            printf("%4d", matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n\t");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Sé que es poco ético de mi parte recomendar [una respuesta mía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/443773/c%c3%b3mo-recibir-un-char-como-double-en-c/446959#446959), pero te sugeriría que le echaras un vistazo para saber otras maneras mejores de leer enteros que con scanf. Espero te sean útiles las respuestas :)